# What does "possible" mean in this compensation context?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales

This [article](https://bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-49256251) is titled "Paddington station: Commuter gets £27k for 'possible pigeon poo slip'". Later in the article is say the compensation was payed out after "possibly slipping". Finally, it references a "possible lacerated finger" as a cause for compensation payout.

What does possible/possibly mean in this context? Is it that cause was possibly the fault of the party making the payout or that it was possible that the slip happened, or some other meaning?

Comment: Article: https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-london-49256251

Comment: @Moo thank you!

Comment: Possible injury isnt something used in court. Perhaps the party being sued (the authority in charge of paddington station) settled out of court with the claimant, and maintains that they never caused injury. I.e they concede liability but they deny any injury taking place.

Comment: I live 5 mins away from the station and use it for my daily commute. What i would give for a possible pidgeon poo slip and be awarded something like that haha

Answer (score 3):

From the news article alone, one cannot tell just what is meant by "possible" here. My guess is that the passenger claimed that the event happened, the railway has not conceded that it did, but would rather settle than pay the costs of defending the case, and take the risk of a large verdict, and the risk of negative publicity. So "possibly" would mean "not proved in court".